# There is anyway to print to view from a Mac a EPL2 file

Tags: zebra-printers, epl

I need to know if. I can open an EPL2 file and print it directly on a Zebra printer. A software or tool which can I use on mac for free maybe.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the zpl printer on your Mac:

> lpstat -p -d

2. Send the epl file directly to the printer driver:

> lpr -P  -o raw